# Returning the SUM of a range of cells from user-input START to END

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

In Google Docs, I am trying to sum the values of selected rows in a table, from position START to END.

Imagining this sample data:

```
Index  VALUE
  1     300
  2     400
  3     750
  4     850
  5     900
  6     1000
```

And two cells where I input START and END:

```
3
5
```

I would like the result to be the sum of columns from value: 750 + 850 + 900

I am trying to use `SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)` but cannot seem to specify a way to use 'between(min, max)' as criteria...

Answer (score 1):

Ok - this isn't simple but it can be done. There may be a more elegant way but here's a way that will work, using only the terms you are providing.

Take a range of cells as follows

```
Col  A   B       C
2    1   300     2
3    2   450     4
4    3   700    
5    4   900    
6    5   1000   
7    6   1200
```

Take these formulas:

```
Cell A10: 
=sumif(A2:A7,"<="&C2,B2:B7)

Cell A11:
=sumif(A2:A7,">="&C3,B2:B7)

Cell B10:
=sum(B2:B7)

Cell A12:
=(A10+A11-B10)*-1
```

Cell A12 will have the results you want. Hopefully you get the idea.

Basically you sum all the data elements *you don't want* in your range, subtract that from the total sum of the range and the remainder is the sum of the range you want.

I didn't do much bug checking for corner cases, but hopefully this will give you enough of a start to solve the problem?

Comment: This idea got me in the right direction. i subtract sum(min) from sum(max), all in the same place: C1 is MIN, C2 is MAX, A is Index, B is Values '=SUMIF(A1:A20,CONCAT("<=",C2),B1:B20) -SUMIF(A1:A20,CONCAT("<=",C1),B1:B20)'

Answer (score 1):

Use worksheet function OFFSET. Suppose your values are in column B (starting from row 2) and that your start and end values are in range C2:C3. Then you have to input: `=sum(offset(B1,C2;0,C3-C2+1,1))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you MIN is E1 and your MAX is F1 then this is the easy way:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(E1,A1:A6),2) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(F1,A1:A6),2)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't give you a `google-spreadsheets` answer because I don't have access to it due to a firewall restriction, but I can give you an `Excel` based answer.

I don't know of a way to give a smart criteria, AFAIK it only allows for "dumb" conditions.

To do what you want you need to define assisting columns - and then hide them to avoid them being visible.

Below is an example of what it looks like:

```
A             B             C             D             E             F
300           1             No                          Min           Max
400           2             Yes                         2             5
750           3             Yes
850           4             Yes
900           5             Yes
1000          6             No            2900
```

Explanation:

- Column A -> contains your actual data
- Column B -> Is a helper column to get each value's Index. Its formula is: `=MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$6)` (Replace `A1` with the actual cell)
- Column C -> Helper column to say if the index is in the range. Its formula is: `=IF(AND(B1>=$E$2,B1<=$F$2),"Yes","No")` (Replace `B1` with the actual cell)
- `E2` contains the minimum index, `F2` contains the maximum index.
- The `D6` cell is the summation - it is defined as `=SUMIF(C1:C6,"=YES",A1:A6)`

I know it is very complicated, but that is the best I could come up with.

Below is how it looks **before hiding the columns**:

[image]